# CLIPS using (not (a-fact $?)) doesn't fire

Tags: clips

I'm having a slight difficulty in understanding how the `not` function interacts with pattern matching. I'd like to write a pattern match that goes "such a fact doesn't exist".

Namely, what I want is:

```
(defrule init-count
    (not (highest-debt ?))
    (catherines ?debt)
    =>
    (assert (highest-debt ?debt))
)
```

and then:

```
(defrule continue-count
    ?debt-fact <- (highest-debt ?h-debt)
    (? ?a-debt)
    (test (> ?a-debt ?h-debt))
    =>
    (retract ?debt-fact)
    (assert (highest-debt ?a-debt))
)
```

But for some reason `not` doesn't work for me here. Replacing `not` with `(not (exists /*pattern*/))` doesn't seem to work either.
Is there something I'm missing and/or a nice way to implement finding the highest number with rules like that?

**Update**

The answer that I have just discovered is this: the `not` pattern shouldn't be the first one (`(declare (salience 0))` doesn't count either). So, the following code works correctly:

```
(defrule init-count
    (catherines ?debt)
    (not (highest-debt ?))
    =>
    (assert (highest-debt ?debt))
)
```

Sorry for bothering :(

Comment: Next time, try to format your code so others are able to read it.

Comment: All the tutorial examples I've seen are formatted like that. Do you want me to add Lisp-style line breaks for every depth level?

Comment: I meant formatting your code in the question. I didn't have comments on your coding styles.

Comment: Sorry, I failed initially, but the current formatting looks kinda okay now, doesn't it?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was actually updating it when you posted your revision. The formatting help tip doesn't remind to put an empty string between plaintext and code blocks.

Answer (score 3):

In versions 6.24 and earlier, when the *not* conditional element was the first pattern in a rule, the pattern (initial-fact) was added before it (this is described in section 5.4.9, Automatic Addition and Reordering of LHS CEs, in the Basic Programming Guide). The (initial-fact) fact is asserted when a (reset) command is performed. I think this is the cause of your problem. Your original rule would have worked if you'd performed a (reset) before asserting your other facts.